# How to size an array in c? 32 bit mcu

Tags: c, arrays, microcontroller

The following line of c code creates an array to store a picture from a camera. The images are about 22kb.

```
uint8_t picturearray[32*1024];
```

The mcu is 32 bit. I'm just wondering why it is `32*1024`? Is it 32 because it is 32 bit? Why would it be 1024?

Thanks

Comment: What pixel format and resolution does the camera use? Most likely notation is used to simply give size in kilobytes (32 x 1024 bytes = 32 kilobytes).

Comment: The answer depends on a lot of things. Your question cannot be answered with that little information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an attempt to write self-documenting code. `32 * 1024` hints of "give me 32kb". It is clearer than `32768`, which would just be a strange "magic number" with no explanation given.

(But obviously not clear enough, or you wouldn't be asking this question.)

An even clearer way to write the same would have been something like:

```
#define SIZE_32KB (32u * 1024u)
...
uint8_t picturearray [SIZE_32KB];
```

or perhaps

```
#define SIZE_KB 1024u
...
uint8_t picturearray [32u * SIZE_KB];
```

---

NOTE: on a 8/16 bit system, `32 * 1024` will be a severe bug! It would give integer overflow and undefined behavior. Use `u` suffix on the integer constants like above, in order to make the code portable.

Answer (score 2):

It is that because it wants 32 kilobytes of memory. One kilobyte is 1024 bytes, and `32*1024` is 32 kilobytes.